# Azure DevOps: HTTP 503 curl 22 error when pushing to remote repo

Tags: git, azure, http, azure-devops, version-control

I'm trying to push a (large) repo to my remote repo.
It was first stuck at 79% of writing objects, I then increased the https.postBuffer to max size, it's working till 100% but now I have this error after waiting for +- 5mins:

> The requested URL returned error: 503 send-pack: unexpected disconnect
> while reading sideband packet

I've read this is a server-side error and that I can't do anything about it, is it right?
Otherwise, what should I do? I always have errors while trying to push so I believe it's not a server-side issue.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 503 status means "Service Unavailable".  All 500-series errors indicate that there's a server-side problem, and this one is no exception.  If there were a client-side problem that you can address, the server would return a 400-series error, and you'd know that you needed to retry your requests differently to fix the problem.  However, with a 503 error, the server is admitting that it is broken and cannot serve your request.

As a result, you should report this breakage to Azure DevOps and ask them to fix it.

Note that unless you are sure you need it, [you should not adjust `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo).  In any case where that option has an effect, the server or a middlebox is broken or misconfigured and should be fixed instead.